# Why the list never empty and why it's never add a new items?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;
using UnityEditor;
using UnityEditorInternal;
using UnityEngine;

[CustomEditor(typeof(ObjectsReplace))]
public class ObjectsReplaceEditor : Editor
{
    private string addkey = "1";

    public override void OnInspectorGUI()
    {
        base.OnInspectorGUI();

        ObjectsReplace myTarget = (ObjectsReplace)target;

        if (GUILayout.Button("Add"))
        {
            addkey = GUILayout.TextField("1", addkey);
        }
    }
}
```

And

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class ObjectsReplace : MonoBehaviour
{
    public List<GameObject> objectsToReplace = new List<GameObject>();
}
```

But in the inspector I see the old list I created before and it's never adding a new textfield with the number 1 or what I want is to add a new item to list each time click on add. The textfield is for testing.

[image: List in inspector]

Answer (score 0):

```
 if (GUILayout.Button("Add"))
        {
            addkey = GUILayout.TextField("1", addkey);
        }
```

Basically what happens here is that when the user clicks the `Add` button, for a single frame the inspector will render a text input field with the string `1` in it, and then

I'm assuming you want to add new items to your list, in that case inside your button click handling you will need to actually modify the array, i.e.:

`myTarget.disappear.objectsToReplace.Add(new GameObject())`